# How to cast closure to character in R?

Tags: r, closures, shiny

I want save the data by user input.
And I'll use a `sprintf` with it.
below is my code.

ui.r

```
selectInput(
  "ModelCB", 'Model', choices=NULL, selected = NULL, multiple = FALSE
)
```

server.r

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) 
{  
    output$SelectModel <- renderText({   
    paste("You have selected", input$ModelCB)  
    GetModel <- input$ModelCB  
    })    
    TargetModelQuery <- sprintf("SELECT tb_result.mid 
                                 FROM   tb_result
                                 WHERE  name='%s' and result='F'", GetModel)     
})
```

I can not use a `GetModel`.
`TargetModelQuery` has error.
How can I use a `GetModel`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the `TargetModelQuery` reactive, something like,

```
TargetModelQuery <- reactive({
    sprintf("SELECT tb_result.mid 
             FROM   tb_result
             WHERE  name='%s' and result='F'", input$ModelCB)
})
```

and access the string by calling `TargetModelQuery()`.

Full example

```
library(shiny)
shinyApp(
    shinyUI(
        fluidPage(
            selectInput(
                "ModelCB", 'Model', choices=c("a","b","c"), selected = NULL, multiple = FALSE
            ),
            textOutput("printStr")
        )
    ),
    shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {  
        TargetModelQuery <- reactive({
            sprintf("SELECT tb_result.mid 
                     FROM   tb_result
                     WHERE  name='%s' and result='F'", input$ModelCB)
        })
        output$printStr <- renderText({
            TargetModelQuery()
        })
    })
)
```

Comment: Thanks. one more ask. I'll use a dbGetQuery(). It requires an arguement type is character vector. when i use a dbGetQuery(conn, TargetModelQuery()), it occured a error.